# Installing MEAD Dependency error

Tags: installation, yum, centos-7, dependencies

I am trying to install a program called MEAD.
When doing

```
sudo yum localinstall mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64.rpm
```

I get this:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64 (/mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64 (/mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
Error: Package: mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64 (/mead-2.2.9-12.1.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am a beginner in Linux and have really no idea what to do. I tried installing manually the dependencies, but this leads to more dependencies...

```
uname -rmi
3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64

cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by rebuilding the source file using

```
rpmbuild --rebuild file.src.rpm
```

and then running yum localinstall again